# Is a vector's linear coefficients on non-orthogonal vectors equal to its projection on them?

Tags: vectors

[image]

Couldn't solve this question. When I went through its solution

[image]

They start with $$\textbf{s} = 4\textbf{p} + 3\textbf{q} + 5\textbf{r}\hspace{5pt}(i)$$
I remembered any vector, say $a$
$$\textbf{a} = x\hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k}$$
$$ = (\textbf{a.}\hat{i})\hat{i} + (\textbf{a.}\hat{j})\hat{j} + (\textbf{a.}\hat{k})\hat{k}$$
This works because doing the dot product with (i) gives
$$\textbf{a.}\hat{i} = x $$
and similarly with the other orthogonal unit vectors, but does generalize to any set of 3 vectors?

 This should definitely work with all sets of orthogonal vectors even if they aren't unit ones because doing the dot product would still result in the above statement (albeit with the addition of dividing by the square of its magnitude), but what if they aren't orthogonal? 
Would this still hold? because doing the above process won't cancel out the other components.

Comment: It will work, but the magnitude of the vector is no longer given by the sum of the square of the components (no longer $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$)

Comment: @Andrei
Is there a proof for this? how does
$$a=xp+yq+zr$$
imply
$$x=a.p/||p$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $x=a\cdot p/||p||^2$ formula is not valid for non-orthogonal lattices. You need to introduce a reciprocal lattice. You will get $$p^*=\frac{q\times r}{p\cdot(q\times r)}$$ and similar for the $q^*$ and $r^*$ vectors.
If the lattice is orthogonal, then $q\times r$ is along $p$, so we can write $$q\times r=||q\times r||\frac{p}{||p||}$$
Then $$p*=\frac{p}{||p||^2}$$
Notice that $p\cdot p^*=1$ and $q\cdot p^*=r\cdot p^*=0$. Then $$a\cdot p^*=x(p\cdot p^*)+y(q\cdot p^*)+z(r\cdot p^*)=x+0y+0z=x$$
If you want to get more information, this is the basis of crystallography. Look up reciprocal lattice.

Comment: so then the answer would be wrong right? or they are using the word 'component' in the sense that it is the coefficient in the linear combination and NOT the projection?

Comment: I understand it as the coefficient of the linear combination